# dconf editor missing options

Tags: gnome, dconf

Ever since I installed dconf-editor a few months ago, I noticed I don't have all the options many tutorials tell me I should have? For example I was trying out gnome today and wanted to tweak it with this article: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/add-categories-to-gnome-shell-dashboard but I just don't have the options listed there:

[image: OMG Ubuntu]

Same happens when I'm trying to tweak unity.

What I see:

[image]

I tried to run the program as sudo, same happened..

Comment: Can you list the desired options?

Comment: It's in the screenshots now.